# NSInternalInconsistencyException after UITableView reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem when I add an object in the `NSMutableArray` linked to my `UITableView` after a `reloadData`...

I got this error :

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:7344
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

**Add :**

```
self.relatedArtists = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Artist* test = [[Artist alloc]init];
test.name = @"Test 1";
[self.relatedArtists addObject:test];

Artist* test2 = [[Artist alloc]init];
test2.name = @"Test 2";
[self.relatedArtists addObject:test2];

[self.artists reloadData];
```

**`numberOfRowsInSection` & `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.relatedArtists count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.artists dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ARTIST_CELL_ID"];

    Artist *artist = self.relatedArtists[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = artist.name;

    return cell;
}
```

I think I missed something in the `Main.storyboard` file, but I don't see what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed setting identifier of your tableView cell in storyboard to `ARTIST_CELL_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the tableviewcell with the given reusablecellidentifier "ARTIST_CELL_ID" also.

Example code is given below.

```
[yourTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YouTableViewCellNibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```